Unable to open app settings in iOS 18 MAUI
Has anyone encountered an issue in their MAUI program where opening the app settings works on earlier iOS versions but fails on iOS 18?
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString));

I am receiving an error message below:
**"BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: The caller of UIApplication.openURL(_:) needs to migrate to the non-deprecated UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:). Force returning false (NO)."**

The issue occurs because Apple has deprecated UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl in favor of the newer UIApplication.Open API, a change that began with iOS 10 and is enforced more strictly in iOS 18. The error message indicates that your code must be updated to utilize this modern API.
Updated Code
To resolve this, replace your UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl call with the UIApplication.SharedApplication.Open method, ensuring you use the appropriate options and completion handler. Here’s how you can implement the fix:
var url = new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString);

if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(url))
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url, new UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions(), (success) =>
    {
        if (!success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to open app settings.");
        }
    });
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cannot open app settings URL.");
}


This fix works. But you still use the OpenUrl method on this fix. Where are we using the UIApplication.SharedApplication.Open method? I checked the class and there is no Open method, but there are overload method for the OpenUrl which is the one you suggested. Is that correct?

@error404
The UIApplication.SharedApplication.Open method doesn't exist as a separate API. Instead, the recommended approach is to use the overloaded versions of OpenUrl. These include additional parameters like options (UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions) and a completion handler.
You can use either above suggestion:
OR

try
{
    var url = new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString);

    if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(url))
    {
        var success = await UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrlAsync(url, new UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions());
        if (!success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to open app settings.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot open app settings URL.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}


First of all, the UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(NSUrl url) was deprecated. But the OpenUrl(NSUrl url, NSDictionary options, [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDActionArity1V4))] Action<bool>? completion) is still supported. And Sanjay Hans used this method.
In addition, Maui has added OpenUrlAsync(NSUrl url, UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions options) api. You can use it:
await UIApplication.SharedApplication
             .OpenUrlAsync(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString), 
                     new UIApplicationOpenUrlOptions());

